# what will happen if my virtual machine too slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

i have a newbie question in here, but i'm new to clouds and linux, i'm using google cloud now and wondering when choosing a machine config

what if my machine is too slow? will it make the app crash? or just slow it down

how fast should my vm be? in the image bellow
[image]

last 6 hours of a python scripts i'm running and it's cpu usage, it's obviously running for less than %2 of the cpu for most of it's time, but there's a small spike, should i care about the spike? and also, how much should my cpu usage be max before i upgrade? if a script i'm running is using 50-60% of the cpu most of the i assume i'm safe, or what's the max before you upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what if my machine is too slow? will it make the app crash? or just
> slow it down

It depends.

Some applications will just respond slower. Some will fail if they have timeout restrictions. Some applications will begin to thrash which means that all of a sudden the app becomes very very slow.

A general rule, which varies among architects, is to never consume more than 80% of any resource. I use the rule 50% so that my service can handle burst traffic or denial of service attempts.

Based on your graph, your service is fine. The spike is probably normal system processing. If the spike went to 100%, I would be concerned.

Once your service consumes more than 50% of a resource (CPU, memory, disk I/O, etc) then it is time to upgrade that resource.

Also, consider that there are other services that you might want to add. Examples are load balancers, Cloud Storage, CDNs, firewalls such as Cloud Armor, etc. Those types of services tend to offload requirements from your service and make your service more resilient, available and performant. The biggest plus is your service is usually faster for the end user. Some of those services are so cheap, that I almost always deploy them.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose machine family based on your needs. Check the link below for details and recommendations.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types

If CPU is your concern you should create a `managed instance group` that automatically scales based on CPU usage. Usually 80-85% is a good value for a max CPU value. Check the link below for details.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cpu

You should also consider the availability needed for your workload to keep costs efficient. See below link for other useful info.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/choose-compute-deployment-option